# What is better form for getting info from an Event?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

What is better form for getting information from a "sender" of an Event?  To Cast to the type of the known sender, or to use the name directly?  I suspect casting would be better form, but it seems a rather circuitous way to go about things if you know the name anyways.  Here are the examples that I am contemplating:

```
protected void OnEntry1Changed (object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            if ((sender as Gtk.Entry).Text != "some specific value" && (sender as Gtk.Entry).Text != "" && anotherEntry.Text !="") {
                //  Do some stuff here...
            } else {
                // Do some other stuff here...
            }
        }
```

The other version would be to access the entry directly like this:

```
protected void OnEntry1Changed(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    if (Entry1.Text != "some specific value" && Entry1.Text != "" && anotherEntry.Text !="") {
        //Do some stuff here...
    } else {
        // Do some other stuff here...
    }
}
```

...it seems that the second version would be more direct, but is one or the other considered more "correct code form"?

Comment: I'd actually prefer to get the new value in my EventArgs.

Comment: Can you explain who to do that?  It seems in my "e", I only have "Equals","GetHashCode", "GetType" and "ToString"...

Comment: You can only do that if you control the class that send those events. In this case, simply inherit EventArgs and add the nesseccary properties. If you don't control it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to do the top one - `(sender as Gtk.Entry)`. That way, if you had to duplicate the functionality of that entry somewhere else in your application, you could reuse the signal handler.

Comment: SO the point being that its probably better to give priority to code maintainability,then?  This makes good sense.